# HoC with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to port from `class component` to `react hooks` with `Context API`, and I can't figure out what is the specific reason of getting the error.

#### First, my Codes:

```
// contexts/sample.jsx
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react'
const SampleCtx = createContext()

const SampleProvider = (props) => {
  const [ value, setValue ] = useState('Default Value')
  const sampleContext = { value, setValue }
  return (
    <SampleCtx.Provider value={sampleContext}>
      {props.children}
    </SampleCtx.Provider>
  )
}

const useSample = (WrappedComponent) => {
  const sampleCtx = useContext(SampleCtx)
  return (
    <SampleProvider>
      <WrappedComponent
        value={sampleCtx.value}
        setValue={sampleCtx.setValue} />
    </SampleProvider>
  )
}

export {
  useSample
}
```

---

```
// Sends.jsx
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSample } from '../contexts/sample.jsx'

const Sends = (props) => {
  const [input, setInput ] = useState('')

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value)
  }
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    props.setValue(input)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setInput(props.value)
  }, props.value)

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input value={input} onChange={handleChange} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

#### Error I got:

> Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

#### Explanation for my code:

I used `Context API` to manage the states, and previously I used `class component`s to make the views. I hope the structure is straightforward that it doesn't need any more details.

I thought it should work as well, the `<Sends />` component gets passed into `useSample` HoC function, and it gets wrapped with `<SampleProvider>` component of `sample.jsx`, so that `<Sends />` can use the `props` provided by the `SampleCtx` context. But the result is failure.

Is it not valid to use the `HoC` pattern with `React hooks`? Or is it invalid to hand the mutation function(i.e. `setValue` made by `useState()`) to other components through `props`? Or, is it not valid to put 2 or more `function components` using `hooks` in a single file? Please correct me what is the specific reason.

Comment: @JosephD. I fixed the typo, and that is a trivial one. I didn't use `<Consumer />` because I wanted to use `useContext` instead. Do I have to use `<Consumer />` even if I use the `useContext` hook?

Comment: Nope. `useContext()` and `<Consumer />` are equivalent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So HOCs and Context are different React concepts. Thus, let's break this into two.

**Provider**

Main responsibility of the provider is to provide the context values. The context values are consumed via `useContext()`

```
const SampleCtx = createContext({});

export const SampleProvider = props => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("Default Value");
  const sampleContext = { value, setValue };

  useEffect(() => console.log("Context Value: ", value)); // only log when value changes

  return (
    <SampleCtx.Provider value={sampleContext}>
      {props.children}
    </SampleCtx.Provider>
  );
};
```

**HOC**

The consumer. Uses `useContext()` hook and adds additional props. Returns a new component.

```
const withSample = WrappedComponent => props => { // curry
  const sampleCtx = useContext(SampleCtx);
  return (
    <WrappedComponent
      {...props}
      value={sampleCtx.value}
      setValue={sampleCtx.setValue}
    />
  );
};
```

Then using the HOC:

```
export default withSample(Send)
```

Composing the provider and the consumers (HOC), we have:

```
import { SampleProvider } from "./provider";
import SampleHOCWithHooks from "./send";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SampleProvider>
        <SampleHOCWithHooks />
      </SampleProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/zen-williamson-8m9lw) for full code.

Comment: eslint will produce a warning for the HOC because hooks cannot be called inside callback methods. `React Hook "useContext" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.eslint(react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)`

Comment: 2022: this error happens when HoC's have start with an upper case character

Answer (score 6):

Higher order Components are functions that takes a Component and returns another Component, and the returning Components can be class component, a Functional Component with hooks or it can have no statefull logic.
In your example you're returning jsx from useSample.

```
const useSample = (WrappedComponent) => {
  const sampleCtx = useContext(SampleCtx)
  return ( // <-- here
    <SampleProvider>
      <WrappedComponent
        value={sampleCtx.value}
        setValue={sampleCtx.setValue} />
    </SampleProvider>
  )
}
```

if you want to make a HOC what you can do is something like this

```
const withSample = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return props => {
        const sampleCtx = useContext(SampleCtx)
        <WrappedComponent
            value={sampleCtx.value}
            setValue={sampleCtx.setValue} {...props} />
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but in that case, the `context` doesn't get generated properly. `sampleCtx` is `undefined`, which means the `useContext` does not generate a `context` properly.

Comment: Plus, don't we have to still use `<SampleProvider />`?

Comment: provider should wrap the whole section of the app where you want to access the context state, you don't need to wrap each component in a provider. for example if you want this data to be available in your whole app then wrap your root component with the provider.